# Make Underscorejs functions functioning on generators

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, generator

I have dozens of functions acting on arrays. See [here](https://github.com/bacloud14/dz_listings/blob/1221e066fe1b4a88559594562ac99e6b42dbc20f/helper.js) for the sake of illustration.

As you can see I am using **Underscorejs** for most operations.

However I want to write a transformation on my main iteratee which is a list of JSON objects like the following:

```
var listings = [{ title: 'title1', d: 0, desc: 'hello world', pass: 'qub7s1ya', tags: ["tag1", "tag2"] }]
```

As I want to really optimize performance, I want to write a transformer on `desc` values. I will be using **lzutf8** for this; So that I store in disk and in memory only compressed values. On each **Underscorejs** operation I would like to act on the decompressed value of key `desc`.

Apparently, **Underscore** operations do not act on generators directly, so my question is how to achieve this ?

Edit1: I believe all operations of **Underscorejs** are sequential, so why not support generators ? or am I missing something ?

Edit2: The operations are those acting on "key-value" in a JSON object or an array like

> _#filter, _#findWhere, _#where, _#reject, _#pick

Comment: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/2147

Comment: So it is ongoing and it is being implemented for few operations

Comment: From the cursory search I've done, it actually seems there isn't much interest. I mean, ES6 is 5 years old already… Nobody seems to be using underscore (or lodash, for that matter) with modern loops or fancy iterators.

Comment: probably, when you have the mental and & will power to write again all array function there. not me though :)

Comment: "Apparently, Underscore operations do not act on generators directly, so my question is how to achieve this ?" Please illustrate what you'd *like* to be able to do, otherwise it's going to be hard to answer your question.

Comment: @Bergi "You don't need Underscore anymore because of ES6" is a common sentiment that everyone keeps repeating after each other, but it's fundamentally untrue. Most of Underscore's functionality is still *not* available from vanilla JavaScript, so unless you want to reinvent the wheel all the time, you use (a library like) Underscore.

Comment: @Julian Yes, it's common but wrong. On the other hand, it seems nobody is using native ES6 features and Underscore together - they must've switched to different libraries that do properly support iterators.

Comment: @Julian Sure, I will edit to post later for illustrations to show exactly my use cases. meanwhile, I forgot about "getters" and this will probably save my time as attaching a getter at runtime is possible and it would be a calculated property. see my attempt answering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I thought of generators to be able to change each item at runtime to be able to have an plain text from a compressed one. Similarly (I think at least for now), it can be achieved by attaching a calculated property to a JSON object, this is possible in JavaScript. Something like:

```
var item = {
    desc: "compressed text", 
}

Object.defineProperty(item, 'desc_', {
  get: function() { return decompress(this.desc) }
});
console.log(item.desc_)
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)))
```

Then I don't worry about other functions acting on `desc` only by replacing `desc` by `desc_`.

Also apparently adding a function using `Object.defineProperty` does not affect `JSON.stringify` in contrary to redefining another JSON with a `getter` like:

```
var item = {
    desc: "hello world", 
    get desc_(){ return (this.desc.toUpperCase()); },
    toJSON() {
      return {
        desc: this.desc 
      }
  }
}
```

where `toJSON` must be defined otherwise `desc_` will be calculated and persisted (for some reason!).

Back to `Underscore.js` question. All needed operations seem to work with the new calculated property.

Example of where:

```
listings = [{ title: 'title1', d: 0, desc: 'oipfjezojifze', pass: 'qub7s1ya', tags: ["tag1", "tag2"] }]
listings.forEach(item => {
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'desc_', {
        get: function () { return (this.desc.toUpperCase()) }
    });
});
var results = _.where(listings, { desc_: "oipfjezojifze".toUpperCase() })
// it also returns the object intact
console.log(results[0].desc_)
// and other methods _#filter, _#findWhere, _#where, _#reject, _#pick do as well
```